# Aws ec2 instance corrupted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops

Please answer this. If the aws ec2 custom ami and running ec2 instance is corrupted. Then how can we take the back up and restore the instance with same configuration?

Comment: How do you know that your instance is "corrupted"? What are you seeing, what error messages occur? Please edit your question to add more information, such as what you are doing to try to access the instance, what problems you are experiencing and what you have tried to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you don't have a way to back and restore if your instance and its AMI both corrupted. But if you have snapshots of the EBS volume for lets say one month, you can try to find a snapshot thats not corrupted. Thats why the EC2 life cycle management policy becomes handy, you can have a policy to take the backups and keep the backups for a specific period.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thnk you for the answer

Comment: An AMI can't become corrupted.  AMIs are immutable, so if an AMI is initially intact and valid, that fact doesn't change later.

Comment: I thought what he meant by currupted Ami is that the  Ami is created from a currupted instance. That's possible right

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no options, to take a backup from a corrupted Instance, but there are some options that you can try to recover the corrupted Instance:

[1] You always have an option to try and boot the Instance to Last Know Good Configuration, if you are facing any booting Issues. You can use a troubleshooting tool, called EC-2 Rescue for Windows instance which resolves many issue.

[A] EC-2 Rescue: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2rescue-windows-troubleshoot/

[2] Also, you have the option to use some system checker tools like chkdsk and sfc /scannow to scan Windows and restore your files.

[A] chkdsk: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk
[B] sfc /scannow: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system